# String calculation

Tags: c, string

I got an excersice to make a string calculator which only has an add function. When digits are not seperated, the digits have te make one whole number. When the input is 11 the program may not do 1 + 1 but has to make it eleven.

When I execute the following program it is printing "Sum = 111" on my screen, does anyone know why it is not printing 11 and maybe has a solution?

```
int main(void)
{
int sum = Add("11");

if(sum == -1)
{
    printf("Can not return a sum");
}
else
{
    printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);
}
}

extern int Add(char* numbers)
{
size_t string_length = strlen(numbers);
int Sum = 0;
int index = 0;
char number_string[255];
int number = 0;

if(string_length == 0)
{
    Sum = 0;
    return Sum;
}
else if(string_length == 1)
{
    if(isdigit(numbers[0]))
    {
    Sum = numbers[0] - '0';
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return Sum;
}
else if(string_length >= 2)
{
    for(index; index <= string_length; index++)
    {
        if(isdigit(numbers[index]))
        {
            strcat(number_string, &numbers[index]);
        }
        else if(!isdigit(numbers[index]))
        {
            Sum += atoi(number_string);
            memset(number_string, 0, 255);
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return Sum;
}
else
{
    return -1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you function uses strcat, you can debug and see how it works:

1. 1st iteration - append string "11" (&numbers[0] points to begin of the string) to number_string
2. 2nd iteration - append string "1" (&numbers[1] points to 2nd symbol) to number_string

this is how you get "111"

what you need to do is to convert your string to number without concatenation, like this:

```
int Add(char* numbers) {
    int n = 0;
    for (; *numbers; numbers++)
        if (isdigit(*numbers))
            n = n*10 + (*numbers - '0');
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is printing 11 now:)

Answer (score 0):

Your `strcat` cats `11` and then cats `1` to number string, so you the `111`.  Here is a simple way to do this without any built in functions other than `printf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sum = -1;
  printf("%d\n", argc);
  if (argc == 2) {
     sum = Add(argv[1]);
  }

  if(sum == -1)
  {
      printf("Can not return a sum\n");
  }
  else
  {
      printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);
  }
}

int Add(char* numbers)
{
  char *ptr = numbers;
  char *end = numbers;
  int sum = 0;
  while (*end >= '0' && *end <= '9') {
      end++;
  }
  for( ; ptr < end; ptr++) {
    sum *= 10;
    /* *ptr is always positive */
    sum += *ptr - '0';
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me what happens in the last for loop with that hexadecimal number? I'm quite new to C.

Comment: I was just masking it to 8 bits.